# Django and dates in UTC

Tags: django

I use Django with `USE_TZ` set to `True`. I also set my `TIME_ZONE`. The thing is datetimes are stored in DB in UTC (-2 hours to my timezone). But when I print the datetime to template it's still in UTC.

How do I automaticaly tell Django to print the datetimes in my local timezone (which should be default behavior).

I use MySQL and datetime is saved as `2016-09-20 22:00:00` which is `2016-09-21 00:00:00` in my local timezone.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you activating a different timezone at any point in the request?

Comment: No at all......

Comment: Can you add how you're display the datetime in your template?

Comment: {{ my_date|date:"j.n.Y" }} or sometimes I use "SHORT_DATE_FORMAT"

Comment: Can you add the model that has the field being rendered? And are you saving a datetime or a date instance to it?

Comment: I do use this: signed = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True) and I save date (in particular places I will save datetime)

Comment: If you're saving a date in a datetime field, you're losing the timezone information. That's likely the problem.

Comment: Ah, thank you. How should I fix my date to be aware of timezone?